# Codeigniter having trouble on delete_cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

i'm having a hard time doing this. Can you please help me.
i am trying to delete cookie. this is my code

```
 $mydomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; //domain name eg. localhost
 $mypath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'/'; // eg. logistics/core/waybill                    
 delete_cookie('theme', $mydomain,$mypath);
```

but if i use this my delete_cookie is running well..

```
delete_cookie('theme', 'localhost','/logistics/core/waybill/');
```

Comment: You may have to access the page from the same domain.  if you are accessing the page as http://localhost, you will not be able to delete a cookie for .example.net.

Comment: what do you mean sir?

Comment: when you are attempting to delete the cookie for some other domain, like ".example.net", are you accessing the page as "http://www.example.net" or as "http://localhost"?  if you are accessing the page as "http://localhost" the delete cookie will have no effect.  You have to access the page as http://www.example.net for the delete cookie to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete cookies as:

```
delete_cookie("name");
```

or

```
delete_cookie($name, $domain, $path);
```